# Django Admin - when editing user his password is also needed and updated

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I am using custom User model and Django Admin - when I update user via the admin, it screws up the password and saves it in plain text instead of encrypted (I have to type the password in the form, the field is required).

What should I do if I want to be able to edit the user without password at all?

I read [Django admin. Edit user and leave password unchanged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54289544/django-admin-edit-user-and-leave-password-unchanged) but I think the answer there does not apply to my situation - I do not have any code for the admin in the views.

models.py:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
  class Meta:
    db_table = 'app_user'

  allow_emails = models.BooleanField(default=False)
  accept_privacy_policy = models.BooleanField(default=False)
  email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
```

settings.py:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "app.User"
```

admin.py

```
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   list_display = ["username", "email", "allow_emails", "accept_privacy_policy", "date_joined", "is_staff", "is_superuser"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In your admin.py, your `UserAdmin` should inherit from `from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin`

```py
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin

class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
   list_display = ["username", "email", "allow_emails", "accept_privacy_policy", "date_joined", "is_staff", "is_superuser"]
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that was exactly what I was missing :) However now the edit form in the admin is missing my custom fields. Is there a way to add those custom fields (e.g. allow_emails), without having to use custom view as well?

Comment: Ahh I found the answer  - I can just specify the fields in the admin.py via fieldsets as described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/53356561/1757181

Answer (score 0):

What I will suggest is to manually create a form. As an example:

```py
class UpdateNameForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name')
```

You can specify the fields that you wish to be changed. Then you can render it through another view:

```py
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class ChangeNameView(generic.edit.UpdateView):
    model = models.User
    template_name = 'myaccount/change_name.html'
    form_class = forms.UpdateNameForm


    def get_object(self):
        return self.request.user

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('profile', kwargs={'slug': self.object.slug})
```

It's definitely more work, but I will recommend this method when you want to customize Django's default utilities as Django does not provide everything.